# how to display first page before loading all the data in Active Reports 6.0

Tags: c#, winforms, activereports

I have a win-form application which has some report. And I am using Active Reports 6.0 for displaying reports. I am using a list which is bind with data source for binding active reports.

The problem is that this list has lots of data and first it loads full record and then bind with data source so displaying time of report is very late. So I was thinking that when the list is getting some data at that time active report should display some of pages which has been loaded in list and simultaneously this list continue loading all the data.

I am using this code for displaying reports

```
ActiveReport ar=new ActiveReport();
ar.DataSource=lstalldata;
ar.Run();
```

So it is possible to run report before getting all record from list? I am stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following blog post wherein it is discussed how you can optimize the performance of ActiveReports when bound to very large data:

http://our.componentone.com/2013/04/08/how-to-optimize-performance-of-section-report/

Regards,
Mohita

Answer (score 1):

You may also try using the Run(boolean) method and set its syncDocument parameter to true. You can get the code snippet example [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/topic3805.html).

Regards, Mohita

Answer (score 0):

```
I suggest one thing that if your page containing **Page Count** field so remove that field from page then you will get impact your active report performance.

It's default feature of active report that it load first page immediately and rest of them will continue loading. if your page hold **Page Count** field then it will wait to display first page until last page load.And one thing more run your report AsysnChronous mode
using below code

ActiveReport ar=new ActiveReport();
ar.DataSource=lstalldata;
this.ar=ar;
MethodInvoker mi=new MethodInvoker(RunReportAsynChronous)
mi.BeginInvoke(null,null);



Private void RunReportAsynChronous()

{

 if(this.ar !=null)

  {
   this.ar.Run();
  }

}
```